# Why assigning a property at init and didUpdateAttrs are different?

Tags: ember.js, ember-components

At [Ember.js Guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_resetting-presentation-state-on-attribute-change-with-code-didupdateattrs-code), there is an example like that:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.errors = [];
  },

  didUpdateAttrs() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('errors', []);
  },

  ...
});
```

Why assigning to `errors` property is different at `init` and 
`didUpdateAttrs`? What are their differences?

**UPDATED** according to @locks answer:

When is observability set? After init? But parent component's values had been assigned to child component's properties before init.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to be mostly with observability. 
On `init`, observability hasn't been set up, so `this.errors = []` and `this.set('errors', [])` are functionally similar.

If you were to do `this.errors = []` inside the `didUpdateAttrs` lifecycle hook, the related computed properties and template wouldn't update. This is because you currently need `get`/`set` to be KVO-compliant.

Comment: When is observability set? After init? Parent component's values had been assigned to child component's properties before init.

Comment: Yup, after init. As far as I'm aware, setting observability is part of Ember.Object's init procedure